# How to have a root query/mutation argument(s) in GraphQL API?

Tags: graphql

I need to have a "global argument" that can be specified (at most) once and applies to the entire request (having however many queries/mutations inside). If I were able to have the client specify it in `query(arg: "value") {...}` and/or `mutation(arg: "value") {...}` I would... but I understand this is reserved for "variables". I dislike other options I am aware of:

1. HTTP header - ties this to HTTP only, not in schema, not documented nicely.

```
POST /graphql
X-MyArg: some-value
...

{"query":"{someQuery{id name}}"}
```

2. HTTP (URL) query string parameter - ugh... I like the single common URL, also same problems as with (1)

```
POST /graphql?myArg=some-value
...

{"query":"{someQuery{id name}}"}
```

3. Introduce an intermediate wrapper field to expose this argument ... but this makes everything longer and I don't know of a way saying "this must be specified/requested at most once", while supporting multiple occurrences makes no sense for at least some of these (e.g. authentication / authorization / security related and others).

```
POST /graphql
...

{"query":"{wrapper(arg: \"some-value\"){someQuery{id name}}}"}
```

4. Cheat/hack and require an `$arg` variable (meant to be defined by the API client(s)) to be specified while somehow preventing the framework I am using from throwing up when that variable isn't actually referenced from anywhere inside.

```
POST /graphql
...

{"query":"query($arg:String){someQuery{id name}}","variables":{"arg":"some-value"}}
```

Can anyone help? Am I missing something or am I really forced to pick one of those poison pills?

Comment: .... and the reason/requirement for *'need to have a "global argument"'* is ... ?

Comment: It should not matter and I cannot disclose. The design is correct, you should not attempt to go there to derail the question. Sure, I can change the design to fit the tool but exactly that would be wrong.

Comment: (I noted that as option #3, BTW)

Comment: Usually this should be #1 or #2 (or both; depends on security expectations; using middleware parsing to context) ... "I cannot disclose" a real/better solution without any (even artificial) use case/context ... you can dislike this, too :p

Comment: @xadm: Thanks, I suspected as much.